# How to get the length of paths in an given font/character

Tags: transformations, computational-geometry, pathtracing, vector-graphics, font-rendering

I wan't create some LED-rope text, using some script font, like the following:

[image]

For this I need somewhat estimate the needed length of the LED-rope for the given letter (or combinations of letters).

Some more info:

- The font will be TTF or FT2.
- I could manage some programs in perl using the FreeType library, eg. read some properties of the character in the font-file - if this helps.
- Also could install Inkscape (Illustrator  open-source alternative) or even could use Illustrator at my friend - if any of this tools could help.

**Looking for some suggestions how to measure the length of paths in the given font for the particular character (or whole text).**

I don't need exact precision, (see the purpose above) and looking for the solution *as simple as possible*, but I haven't any idea how even approach this problem. :(

Of course, I always could print the text and buy some inexpensive [curve runner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opisometer), but would be better to have some computer-based solution. :)

Ps: I'm not fully sure that this is the right place to ask such question, if not - I will delete it, but please suggest some better place.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach this is to get the outline curves of the font and then break each one down into some fixed number of steps (like, say, 100), and make a series of very small straight lines.

So if you've got some bezier curve, you loop `t` from 0 to 1 in 100 steps and plug it into the equation:

```
double x = calculateBezier(0.0, c0.x, c1.x, c2.x, c3.x);
double y = calculateBezier(0.0, c0.y, c1.y, c2.y, c3.y);
double dist = 0.0;
for (double t = 0.01; t <= 1.0; t+= 0.01)
{
    double nextX = calculateBezier(t, c0.x, c1.x, c2.x, c3.x);
    double nextY = calculateBezier(t, c0.y, c1.y, c2.y, c3.y);
    double nextDist = sqrt((nextX - x) * (nextX - x) + (nextY - y) * (nextY - y));
    dist += nextDist;
}
```

Where `calculateBezier()` is a function that calculates a point on a bezier curve given the parameter `t` and control points `c0` through `c3`:

```
double calculateBezier(double t, double c0, double c1, double c2, double c3)
{
    double t1 = 1.0 - t;

    return (t1 * t1 * t1) * c0 + 3.0 * (t1 * t1) * c1 + 
            3.0 * t1 * (t * t) * c2 + (t * t * t) * c3;
}
```

And just add the distances of each part of the curve until you're out of curves.

Note that this assumes cubic bezier curves. For quadratic, the `calculateBezier` function would calculate a quadratic one (like described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_B.C3.A9zier_curves)).

Comment: +1 - just not need break the font into the parts, because the font itself is stored in the `ttf` as a pairs of x-y coordinates. (the connections between the points could be straight or some are quadratic beziers). Also see my answer above - it is _too complicated_ for my use-case. **Thanks** anyway for the answer it kicked me to the right direction - e.g. start studying the ttf font structure. :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve the LED-rope problem using Inkscape as:

- enter the wanted text into the Inkscape
- set the color of the text to yellow
- add new layer above the text and lock the text layer
- in the new layer, manually draw over the letters my own wanted bezier path(s)
- and finally use the tool in `Extensions -> Visualise Path -> Measure Path...` - this adds the length of the given bezier path into the drawing as text.

The reason why:

I studied a bit the ttf-font structure (the whole new world for me). [This blog entry](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=143) and this [Reference manual](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/) helped a lot understanding the following (rough) basics.

- the given glyph (character) is composed from many *closed paths*, e.g. the letter `O` is composed from two paths (outer circle and the inner circle).
- the paths are stored in the font file as pairs of x-y coordinates
- so it isn't so hard to calculate the length of *each* path from the given coordinates.
- *but* - in such way I will get the lengths of the all *outlines*. Creating the outlines using the LED-rope it could be even interesting and also it is used at many examples, (like bellow), but this isn't what I want - I want a simple path(s) - as in the image in the question.
- getting such *simple path* from the font's many outlines would need some tracing and approximation and other complicated math, which is definitely outside of my area of interest.
- therefore (for me) would be much easier just manually create the simple path's and measure their length in the Inkscape.

Also,

- if someone want the length of the font's outlines, it is easily doable
- just need break apart the text into characters
- transform the (font) objects into the strokes
- and use the `Measure path...` tool

[image]